# como Interpolar etiqueta input en otro componente angular

Tags: angular, input, componentes, interpolacion

Soy nuevo en ésto y estoy detenido en la creacion de mi primera appp ... La pregunta es : como hago para que lo que escriba en un 'input type "text"' se vea en otra pagina(componente) sin que haya parentezco entre ellas?

En pocas palabras, quiero hacer un formulario con usuario y contraseña(ya está hecho) con el simple objeto que, al darle click en submit salga en el nuevo componente la leyenda: "Sucursal: {{sucursal}}; Hola {{usuario}}".-

He avanzado mucho y casi lo tengo logrado, pero estoy trabado en la interpolacion de que lo que se escribe en el input del 1er componente salga en el 2do componente...

Creo que la respuesta es por demas de sencilla, pero, por esas cosas, estoy re-trabado...

```
Muchas gracias desde ya a todos...
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! no se angular, pero en react y vue usarias un store... angular no tiene algo asi?? si no, deberias pasar por propiedades al otro componente los valores...

Comment: Sin que se conozcan entre ellos... complicado. Normalmente a los inputs se les pone un @output() para que el padre pueda acceder a esos valores. O un @Input() para pasarle el formulario, y el input se añade a dicho formulario, así con los reactive form tienes siempre acceso total a tu input sin necesitar outputs, y el padre siempre tiene el valor actualizado, puede hacer control de errores... Por cierto, si no añades detalles específicos de la implementación es imposible poder ayudarte. No sabemos qué estás haciendo ni cómo, y en programación hay mil maneras de hacer cada cosa...

Comment: Otra opción sería usar un servicio o alguna gestión de estado como ngrx, pero sinceramente para pasar un valor de un formulario, cuando tienes acceso a los reactive forms... simplemente ponle un @Input y pásale el form y el formControlname que quieras ponerle y ya está. Los reactive form son de lo mejor de angular a la hora de montar formularios, ni callbacks ni nada!